# Remove initial text from ngb-timepicker

Tags: ng-bootstrap, timepicker

I am using this:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples

Copy pasted the following code:

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
```

The result should be like this:
[image]

But it is different in a sense that annoying texts appear: 
[image]

How to remove them? The api documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

those elements have class [sr-only](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/screenreaders/). It is a bootstrap class. According to docs:

> Use screenreader utilities to hide elements on all devices except screen readers

Looks like the styles you use in the project. You might miss some css from bootstrap or some nasty things overrides the `.sr-only` styles.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the bootstrap css wasn't properly applied in my Angular project.
I had to add following line in the global `styles.css`.

`@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ng-version = "1.5"` to the `ngb-timepicker` to remove the annoying texts. Like this:

`<ngb-timepicker ng-version = "1.5" [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>`

That worked for me, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the next:

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time" [spinners]="false"></ngb-timepicker>
```

Those are called "spinners" and are set as "true" by default.
Hope it works for you!

Comment: This is a good additional solution, but for me it removed the ^ and v buttons as well, not just the text.

Answer (score 0):

fast resolve

```
styles: [`
    .visually-hidden{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain some of your code, to make it easier to understand for future readers?

Comment: Explanation: Looking at the elements in the browser's Inspector shows this extra text as having the `.visually-hidden` class.  

This code makes that class `display: none` and the `!important` causes that directive to take precedence over anything higher in the cascade.  (I am not a fan of `!important`, but I can see why it might be useful here).

Answer (score 0):

```
.visually-hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Add this to your style.scss or a seperatly design for the component and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add

```
::ng-deep .visually-hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why does that work? is also important